# Get all Taxonomy from my Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy

Someone a idea how that I can retrieve all my Taxonomy list from Drupal?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();

foreach ($vocabularies as $vocab) {
    $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocab->vid,  0, -1, 1);
        foreach($terms as $term){
               $items[]= l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid");
           }
  }

if(count($items)) {
  return theme('item_list', $items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about something like [**taxonomy_get_vocabularies()**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_vocabularies/5)?

Comment: I will try it? I will retrieve all self made Taxonomies from Drupal. thanks for your comment!

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for.